# List of lists instead of plain list?

Tags: erlang

I'm learing Erlang. Here is a simple task: convert integers like `1011`, `111213`, `12345678` to lists `[10, 11]`, `[11, 12, 13]` and `[12, 34, 56, 78]` correspondingly.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
num_to_list(0) -> [];
num_to_list(Num) -> [Num rem 100 | [num_to_list((Num - Num rem 100) div 100)]].
```

But `num_to_list(1234)` gives me `[34,[12,[]]]`. Now I don't care that the list is reversed. I don't understand why it is not a plain list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

num_to_list returns list. You dont need use [] around it in num_to_list(Num). I mean

```
num_to_list(0) -> [];
num_to_list(Num) -> [Num rem 100 | num_to_list((Num - Num rem 100) div 100)].
```

Comment: But the `num_to_list(1234)` gives me `"\"\f"`. How can I get exactly this list `[12, 34]`?

Comment: in erlang strings are just lists of integers. You need just display result in proper format. Kind of io:format("~w~n",[num_to_list(1234)]).

Comment: Aha! That's great! Gone reading the man further :) Thank you.

Comment: "\"\f" actually string with " (ascii code is 34) and \f -- form feed, ascii code is 12. So from erlang point of view "\"\f" is [34,12].